# Your request can not be treated. The site administrator is notified

Tags: force.com-sites

Here i have four steps Self-registration process in my project.At Final step,if click submit button two times registration failed due to captcha and redirect to same page,at that time i fill 4th step and click submit that time i got 'Your request can not be treated. The site administrator is notified' error.Could you please help me how to fix it.

thank you in advance.

Comment: did site admin get any error mail or did you check your debug. may be it is  a session issue.

Comment: Hi Tushar Sharma, thank you for your response,site admin didn't get any error mails..if i give single click in last step my registration process completed successfully,in case of double click i got this error .